# How to fetch _id from elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have made a searchResponse to fetch data from elasticsearch through java api.

The data is:

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"failed": 0
 },
"hits": {
"total": 2,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "testmerge2",
    "_type": "final",
    "_id": "AWGyd4lYPXZPzBg2Ogp1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user": "kimchy",
      "postDate": "2013-01-30",
      "message": "trying out Elasticsearch",
       }
}
```

Java code to fetch the data:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

SearchResponse sr1 = client.prepareSearch("Index").setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("XXX", XXX)).get();
```

My question is: how do I retrieve the "_id" field from hits?

Comment: Could you please share some code? How did you fetch or How did you printing output.

Comment: I have updated the question. I don't know how to fetch the "_id" field.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SearchResponse sr1 = client.prepareSearch("Index").setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("XXX", XXX)).get();
for (SearchHit searchHit : sr1.getHits().getHits()) {
    String id = searchHit.getId();
}
```